# RecyclerView when navigating back (Navigation Component)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

There is a RuleListFragment fragment with a RecyclerView. The second snippet, RuleFragment, contains detailed information. When going back, the RecyclerView disappears. What could be the problem? The logs say that the adapter is not assigned, but I do not understand where and why.

```
public class RuleListFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RuleAdapter ruleAdapter;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycler, container, false);
        setRecyclerView(view);
        return view;
    }

    public void setRecyclerView(View view) {
        if (recyclerView == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "new!");
            recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "old!");
        }

        if (ruleAdapter == null) {
            List<Rule> rules = Labs.get(getActivity()).getRules();
            ruleAdapter = new RuleAdapter(rules);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(ruleAdapter);
        } else {
            updateRecyclerView();
        }
    }

    public void updateRecyclerView() {
        Log.d(TAG, ruleAdapter == null ? "ruleAdapter = null" : "ruleAdapter != null");
        Log.d(TAG, recyclerView == null ? "recyclerView = null" : "recyclerView != null");
        Log.d(TAG, recyclerView.getAdapter() == null ? "recyclerView.getAdapter() = null" : "recyclerView.getAdapter() != null");
        Log.d(TAG, recyclerView.getLayoutManager() == null ? "recyclerView.getLayoutManager() = null" : "recyclerView.getLayoutManager() != null");
        List<Rule> rules = Labs.get(getActivity()).getRules();
        ruleAdapter.setRules(rules);
        ruleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        Rule rule;
        ImageView icon;
        TextView title;

        private ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

            icon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        }

        private void bind (Rule rule) {
            this.rule = rule;

            int iconId = getResources().getIdentifier(rule.getIcon(), "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
            icon.setImageResource(iconId);
            title.setText(rule.getTitle());
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putSerializable("ruleId", rule.getId());
        Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(getLayout(rule.getType()), args);
        }
    }

    private int getLayout(int i) {
        switch (i) {
            case 1:
                return R.id.generalFragment;
            case 2:
                return R.id.leaderFragment;
            default:
                return R.id.ruleFragment;
        }
    }

    private class RuleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {
        private List<Rule> rules;
        private RuleAdapter (List<Rule> rules) {
            this.rules = rules;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_recycler_rule, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            Rule rule = rules.get(position);
            holder.bind(rule);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return rules.size();
        }

        public void setRules(List<Rule> rules) {
            this.rules = rules;
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class RuleFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getArgument();

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    public void getArgument() {
        int ruleId = getArguments().getInt("ruleId");
        rule = Labs.get(getActivity()).getRule(ruleId);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rule, container, false);

        ///

        return view;
    }



    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_rule, menu);

        ///

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.elect) {
            ///
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Log on first start

```
2020-03-31 02:25:50.190 25212-25212/? D/Constraints: new!
```

Log back

```
020-03-31 02:25:59.023 25212-25212/ D/Constraints: old!
2020-03-31 02:25:59.023 25212-25212/ D/Constraints: ruleAdapter != null
2020-03-31 02:25:59.023 25212-25212/ D/Constraints: recyclerView != null
2020-03-31 02:25:59.023 25212-25212/ D/Constraints: recyclerView.getAdapter() != null
2020-03-31 02:25:59.023 25212-25212/ D/Constraints: recyclerView.getLayoutManager() != null
2020-03-31 02:25:59.065 25212-25212/ E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly I've read from somewhere that it seems you can't set `RecyclerView` in `onCreateView` otherwise you might end with issue like yours.

Can you try moving your `setRecyclerView(view)` in `onViewCreated` ?

Comment: and onViewCreated did not help.

Comment: Have you tried removing the first `if` condition that test the if the `recyclerview` is null ?

Comment: yes, I found a solution, but I don’t know how true it is.

Comment: Yes, when I create recyclerAdapter in onCreateView I face this issue, after moving the adapter creation and recylverView set adapter to onViewCreated method it works. Note Add a condition if its null create new view or adapter

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know how true this decision is, but I redid the code like this. The adapter is now assigned by RecyclerView regardless of whether adapter == null or adapter! = Null. Also removed onResume and notifyDataSetChanged (). I will use the latter only when you need to change the list in RuleListFragment.

```
@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycler, container, false);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        setRecyclerView();
        return view;
    }

    public void setRecyclerView() {
        if (ruleAdapter == null) {
            ruleAdapter = new RuleAdapter(Labs.get(getContext()).getRules());
        } else {
            ruleAdapter.setRules(Labs.get(getActivity()).getRules());
        }
        recyclerView.setAdapter(ruleAdapter);
    }
```